# Trying to redirect traffic to fourth level domain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I'm trying to make simple web fourth level domain and provider of hosting advised me to use htaccess with rewrite rules.
They did not specify more. :(

What I'm trying to do is to have reachable domain4.domain3.domain2.com.
I already know how to do 3rd level domain like domain3.domain2.com via simple domain2.com/_sub/domain3/index.html folder in FTP.

However if i create domain2.com/_sub/domain3/_sub/domain4/index.html it does redirect to what I have in another domain3x.domain2.com. (domain 3x have same name as domain4 I'm trying to put as subdomain).

I of course googled htaccess (and searched this forum) but I'm really not a programmer and all I could find was different of what I'm trying to achieve.
I did some testing from what I have found closest was:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain4\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://domain4.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

AND

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain4\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://domain4.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Which did not work.
All sites there are just simple index.html files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You asked more or less the same question yesterday. You deleted that question and posted this version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426079/trying-to-create-fourth-level-domain-with-htaccess

Comment: We cannot tell you  how your setup reacts, since we do not know your setup. We have no  idea what rewriting rules you already have in place. We have no idea how a http host get's mapped to those folders, only you have access to your configuration and your provider.

Comment: site is probably most simple one you can imagine. I have no rules and this is first time ever I try to use htaccess rules.
All domains have is one html file whi is actually redirect to social network.
One subdomain for FB, anotherone for instagram and now trying to create sub-sub domain which will redirect to linkedin.

Comment: I closed previous question as I thought you cancelled it because I was asking something too specific, mentioning names of domains.
So I posted this question instead. Sorry for confusion. It's my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: Folders have nothing to do with a http host (what you name a "subdomain" or a "subsubdomain"). As said: we don't know any magic your provider might have installed, wen can only work from the generic base technology. Your hosts need to either get explicitly defined in the http server's hsot configuration, or you are using a "defaujt host" for all requests where you then need to separate requests again based on rewriting conditions. But before that you need to make sure that the name resolution works, so you need to take care of the DNS entries. Has that been done? Does that part work?

Comment: Apart from that your question is currently unclear. You will need to use the "edit" button below it. Try to express what you actually want to achieve, not how you might be able to achieve something. Please give specific examples of what requests should get rewritten to what resources in the physical file system on the server side. That is something we might be able to answer.

Comment: Have you tested just RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain4\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain4.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]